# How to solve an undefined reference to function FuzzyObject::InitializeObj()?

Tags: c++

Signed up to ask this question. How come I get an error with code like this?

FuzzyObject.h:

```
#ifndef FUZZYOBJECT_H
#define FUZZYOBJECT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

class FuzzyObject {
public:
    FuzzyObject();
    typedef struct tagFMaterial* FMaterial;
    typedef struct tagFMesh* FMesh;
    typedef struct tagFuzzyForm {
        D3DXVECTOR3 pos;
        D3DXVECTOR3 rot;
        D3DXVECTOR3 scale;
        D3DXVECTOR3 forward;
        D3DXVECTOR3 up;
    } FuzzyForm;

    typedef struct tagObject* Object;

    typedef enum ObjectType {
        FO_STATIC = 0,
        FO_ANIM = 1,
        FO_OBJ = 2,
        FO_CAMERA = 3,
        FO_LIGHT = 4
    } Type;

    typedef enum ObjectCollider {
        BOX = 0,
        SPHERE = 1,
        MESH = 2
    } Collider;

    static FuzzyObject::Object InitializeObj(std::string ObjName, FuzzyObject::ObjectType type, bool render, FuzzyObject::FuzzyForm xform);
    D3DXMATRIX UpdateTransform(FuzzyObject::FuzzyForm xform, FuzzyObject::Object camera);
    void UpdateObject(Object);
    ~FuzzyObject();
};
#endif
```

FuzzyObject.cpp:

```
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <FuzzyObject.h>
#include <Personality.h>
#include <GFX.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

struct tagFMesh{
    LPD3DXMESH mesh;
    LPD3DXBUFFER adjBuf;
    LPD3DXBUFFER materialBuf;
};

struct tagFMaterial {
    LPD3DXEFFECT Shader;
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture0, texture1, texture2;
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 bump0, bump1, bump2;
    D3DXVECTOR4 Color;
    D3DXMATRIX MVP;
};

struct tagObject {
    std::string name;
    FuzzyObject::Type type;
    bool Physics;
    FuzzyObject::Collider collider;
    bool renderable;
    FuzzyObject::FuzzyForm transform;
    D3DXMATRIX FFMATRIX;
    Personality::Behaviour CustomCode;
    FuzzyObject::FMaterial materialDef;
    FuzzyObject::FMesh mesh;
};

D3DXMATRIX FuzzyObject::UpdateTransform (FuzzyObject::FuzzyForm xform, FuzzyObject::Object camera) {
    D3DXMATRIX pos, rot, scale;
    D3DXMATRIX M, V, P;
    D3DXMATRIX MVP;

    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&pos, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&rot, D3DXToRadian(xform.rot.x), D3DXToRadian(xform.rot.y), D3DXToRadian(xform.rot.z));
    D3DXMatrixScaling(&scale, xform.scale.x, xform.scale.y, xform.scale.z);
    D3DXMatrixMultiply(&M, &scale, &rot);
    D3DXMatrixMultiply(&M, &rot, &pos);

    D3DXVECTOR3 from = D3DXVECTOR3(camera->transform.pos.x, camera->transform.pos.y, camera->transform.pos.z);
    D3DXVECTOR3 to = D3DXVECTOR3(cos(camera->transform.rot.x*180/D3DX_PI), tan(camera->transform.rot.y*180/D3DX_PI), sin(camera->transform.rot.z*180/D3DX_PI));
    D3DXVECTOR3 up = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH( &V, &from, &to, &up );
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &P, D3DXToRadian(60.0f), 640/480, 0.01, 1000);

    MVP = M * V * P;
    return MVP;
}

FuzzyObject::Object FuzzyObject::InitializeObj (std::string ObjName, FuzzyObject::ObjectType type,    bool render, FuzzyObject::FuzzyForm xform ) {
    FuzzyObject::Object obj;
    obj->transform = xform;
    obj->name = ObjName;
    obj->type = type;
    obj->renderable = render;
    return obj;
}

void FuzzyObject::UpdateObject(FuzzyObject::Object obj) {
    obj->FFMATRIX = UpdateTransform(obj->transform, NULL);
}
```

What happens is, I get this error in the linker:

```
Error: Undefined reference to 'FuzzyObject::InitializeObj()'
```

from the FuzzyGame.cpp, where the call is done like this:

```
FuzzyObject::Object obj = FuzzyObject::InitializeObj(/*my parameters g here*/);
```

Any ideas? I do not know why it's doing this... :(

Comment: The error message in your title is completely different to the error message shown in your question body. Please clarify exactly which error you are getting.

Comment: Oh shoot! i accidentally got them the wrong way round... :D

Comment: `<classname>` is not a valid classname. Provide your real example.

Comment: This would not even compile if you fixed this; `static` as a prefix on the definition of member functions is invalid. Please take more care over your posts and submit your _actual_ [testcase](http://sscce.org). The one you've been debugging over the last couple of days will be fine.

Comment: Possibly you didn't actually link "header.cpp" (lol?) with the rest of the project. It's too hard to say for sure when you only post some code which isn't even your real code.

Comment: Also, "header.cpp" is kind of a silly name :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation unit that calls `function()` needs to be linked to `header.o`. Most probably this is not specified within your build system. Please produce a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this encourages people to help you.

You must configure your `Dev-C++` project to acknowledge `FuzzyObject.h` and `FuzzyObject.cpp` as dependencies of `FuzzyGame.cpp`. That way, the generated Makefile will contain the proper linkage instructions to resolve the reference to `FuzzyObject::InitializeObj()`.

Good luck with Half-Life 4, we all look forward to it :).

Comment: Could you check the above please, as I have now attached my actual code. And maybe it's because I am using Orwell Dev-C++?

Comment: I am not sure, but it uses GCC 4.8.1 with I think mingw-make32

Comment: I see. Please post the contents of your `Makefile` so we can help you.

Comment: Sure. Note that it's dynamically generated by the compiler though.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually generated by Orwell Dev-C++.

Comment: Fortunately you won't need to modify the Makefile; you will need to edit your project properties on an Orwell Dev-C++ dialog; unfortunately I don't know anything about this IDE; you will need to read its manual.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my makefile people. :)

```
# Project: FLDR-D3D9
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.7.1

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
RES      = FLDR-D3D9_private.res
OBJ      = GFX.o FuzzyObject.o Personality.o Main.o FuzzyGame.o $(RES)
LINKOBJ  = GFX.o FuzzyObject.o Personality.o Main.o FuzzyGame.o $(RES)
LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib32" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-  Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32" -static-libgcc -mwindows ../../../../Dev-Cpp/lib/libd3d9.a ../../../../Dev-Cpp/lib/libd3dx9.a ../../../../Dev-Cpp/lib/libpthreadGC2.a -m32
INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include" -I"C:/Users/112mackailj/Documents/DirectX 9 Projects"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- mingw32/4.8.1/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++" -I"C:/Users/112mackailj/Documents/DirectX 9 Projects"
BIN      = FLDR-D3D9.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) -m32
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) -m32
RM       = rm.exe -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

GFX.o: GFX.cpp
    $(CPP) -c GFX.cpp -o GFX.o $(CXXFLAGS)

FuzzyObject.o: FuzzyObject.cpp
    $(CPP) -c FuzzyObject.cpp -o FuzzyObject.o $(CXXFLAGS)

Personality.o: Personality.cpp 
    $(CPP) -c Personality.cpp -o Personality.o $(CXXFLAGS)

Main.o: Main.cpp
    $(CPP) -c Main.cpp -o Main.o $(CXXFLAGS)

FuzzyGame.o: FuzzyGame.cpp
    $(CPP) -c FuzzyGame.cpp -o FuzzyGame.o $(CXXFLAGS)

FLDR-D3D9_private.res: FLDR-D3D9_private.rc 
    $(WINDRES) -i FLDR-D3D9_private.rc -F pe-i386 --input-format=rc -o FLDR-D3D9_private.res -O coff
```

Comment: Thank you for finding it! :)
But how to modify it to do this? I am a bit noobish with make files... :D